# How can i acces to UEFI on insyde 20 bios R0220E5. Sony Vaio SVE14115FLW

Tags: bios, uefi, sony-vaio

I have windows 10 on my laptop but i'm not sure if i'm running on UEFI, this laptop had Windows 7 by default but i want to run windows 10 on UEFI. The thing is i don't know how to set it to UEFI or if i'm running on UEFI.

My BIOS version is R0220E5.

Comment: It's possible to install and boot Windows 10 under BIOS. Thus, if your reason for wanting to use UEFI is to install Windows 10, don't worry; you can still do it on a BIOS-based computer. If you have another reason for wanting to boot under UEFI, then you might not be able to do it with your computer, but you'll need to dig up technical details on your model. I *suspect* that it's strictly a BIOS firmware (see my comment to Hennes' answer), but I'm not positive of that.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `My BIOS version is R0220E5`. That means that you have no UEFI<sup>*2</sup>.

Basically PC style firmware only ships in two common  configurations.

1. BIOS firmware.
2. UEFI firmware (which can support CSM and boot BIOS'like).

You already stated that you have BIOS loaded into firmware, hence you do have BIOS and not UEFI.

---

There are a few more firmwares, like coreboot, but these are very rare. Non PCs usually used a much broader and more capable range of firmware.

THis assumes that with BIOS you meant BIOS and not UEFI setup program with compatability shims (aka CSM, aka backward BIOS compat mode) enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately, many people, and even manufacturers, refer to EFIs as "BIOSes." Thus, the use of the term "BIOS" is not diagnostic as to whether it's a BIOS or an EFI. That said, Sony's updates page for this model includes files dating to early 2011, which predates the rapid introduction of UEFI for PCs (in late 2011). Thus, chances are the computer is BIOS-based. That's an inference based on limited (and possibly misleading) information, though.